# ReactiveCocoa with MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

i'm very new to this reactive programming. I'm obviously missing a link here.

Ok, so in my view controller at the moment, I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewModel = [[ViewModel alloc]init];

    [RACObserve(viewModel, string) subscribeNext:^(NSString* string){
         NSLog(@"%@", viewModel.string);
    }];

    // This fires the NSLog
    viewModel.string = @"Test12345";

    // This doesn't
    [viewModel test];
}
```

[viewModel test] is...

```
-(void) test{
    _string = @"Test";
 }
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly? I thought this would work.

Thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code that your own answer has covered, but the reason that you're not getting a `next` signal is that you're not setting the string by using `self.string`, instead you're directly accessing the class' variable as `_string`.

[Properties are actually Objective-C methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5) that are cleverly hidden from us, when you call `self.string = @"Test";`, what's actually happening is the automatically created `setString:` method of your class is being called, and its default behaviour is to set `_string` to the newly passed value.

The reason why RAC needs you to do this is that `_string` is just a normal variable and RAC has no way of knowing that this variable has changed. When you use `self.string`, RAC can get notifications from the runtime that the `setString:` method was called via something known as [Key-Value Observation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Good to know the why too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't that far off...

```
[RACObserve(viewModel, string) subscribeNext:^(NSString* string){
     NSLog(@"%@", viewModel.string);
 }];
```

just needs to be

```
[RACObserve(self, viewModel.string) subscribeNext:^(NSString* string){
     NSLog(@"%@", string);
}];
```

AND

```
[viewModel test];
```

becomes

```
[self.viewModel test];
```